# capture exception from running process

Tags: c#, process

I'm running a process which is an EXE file, and it will always run in the background and listen to keyboard events, and i start the EXE file using this code:

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = exeFile;
            startInfo.Arguments = args;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            Process processTmp = new Process();
            processTmp.StartInfo = startInfo;
            processTmp.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            try
            {
                _keyboardListener = processTmp;
                _keyboardListener.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
```

And then it will send some input to my application, but sometimes it will throw an exception, and the process will stop working correctly, but how do i see if the process has thrown an exception? when i measure the exit code an exception is thrown telling me that the process needs to be stopped to get the exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you want to catch your exception you can use in your catch block

```
       try
        {
            _keyboardListener = processTmp;
            _keyboardListener.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.message);

           // OR
          //You can write to any text file using StreamWriter

        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: well the problem is.. it starts fine.. but it will maybe take 5-10 minutes before the process goes down.